# How to show an attribute on a product page outside view.phtml?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php

I want to echo an attribute from a product on the productpage, but not exactly on view.phtml but in tabs.phtml which is loaded into view.phtml with `getChildHtml`.

In view.phtml I can use

```
echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('videotab')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)
```

But when I do the same in tabs.html I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getResource() on null in

How can I echo the product attribute there? I need to add the data inside a tab, so it needs to be loaded inside tabs.phtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$productId = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('videotab')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Comment: I still get: Fatal error: Call to a member function getResource() on null in

Comment: try after clearing cache

Comment: I cleared cache, but I tried this answer before and it didn't work.

Comment: @twan check my updated answer